# Reading dynamic array from Firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a project in ionic3 in which I have Firebase Array as follows.

```
List = {User3: true, User8: true, User9: false}
```

The parameter names are not fixed and can change. So when I receive the array in the above format, I need to list out only the users which are true. I need an array as follows.

```
User = {User3, User8,}
```

Fow do I list out the parameter names in a for loop.

```
for(let item of List){
//I need to write item.User3 in order to retrive the value. But parameter name User3 is not fixed.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List` is not an "array". It's an **object**. It does not have "parameter names". It has **properties**. To get the properties (users) with a value of `true`, filter the object's properties, which you can obtain with `Object.keys`, for ones with a value of `true`. You could do this with something like

```
Object.keys(List).filter(user => List[user])
```

You cannot use `for...of`. That's for arrays, not objects.

You could also query just those nodes with a value of true, which can you find out how to do by consulting the Firebase documentation.

Minor point, but capitalizing variable names is confusing and non-standard. Normally capitalized identifiers are used for classes etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answers if they helped you @TapasMukherjee. Otherwise other SO users may seem that the answer is just a workaround and it's not actually a good way to solve the OP.